# Disable pagination in posts and pages

Tags: posts, pages, pagination, paged

I need to solve duplicating of posts and pages caused by unexpected paging. I am trying to disable the paging with this function, but it seems I miss something:

```
function wpse_disable_pagination( $query ) {
  if( $query->is_single() && $query->is_page() ) {
    $query->set('nopaging', 1 );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_disable_pagination' );
```

Comment: change 1 to true 'nopaging' => true

Comment: It return syntax error:
syntax error, unexpected '=&gt;' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: put your code here i will check it

Comment: sorry mistake please updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right solution, thanks to [Jeff Morris](https://perishablepress.com/wordpress-infinite-duplicate-content/):

```
global $posts, $numpages;

    $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $result = preg_match('%\/(\d)+(\/)?$%', $request_uri, $matches);

    $ordinal = $result ? intval($matches[1]) : FALSE;

    if(is_numeric($ordinal)) {

        // a numbered page was requested: validate it
        // look-ahead: initialises the global $numpages

        setup_postdata($posts[0]); // yes, hack

        $redirect_to = ($ordinal < 2) ? '/': (($ordinal > $numpages) ? "/$numpages/" : FALSE);

        if(is_string($redirect_to)) {

            // we got us a phantom
            $redirect_url = get_option('home') . preg_replace('%'.$matches[0].'%', $redirect_to, $request_uri);

            // if page = 0 or 1, redirect permanently
            if($ordinal < 2) {
                header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 301 Moved Permanently');
            } else {
                header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 302 Found');
            }

            header("Location: $redirect_url");
            exit();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function wpse_disable_pagination( $query ) {
  if( $query->is_single() && $query->is_page() ) {
    $query->set( 'nopaging' , true );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_disable_pagination' );
```

**NOTE: nopaging (boolean) - show all posts or use pagination. Default value is 'false', use paging.**

Comment: It doesn't work with double arrow, it bring syntax error.

Comment: yes it's mistake i am update my code

Comment: you remove pagination on only single post page not in post listing (archive) page?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to remove pagination only in single posts and pages.

Comment: Yes, only on single posts pages.

Comment: ok so it's above code work or not?

Comment: No, the above code doesn't work, still paging posts.